# Google Map API InfoWindow click event not returning latlng

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I created a polygon on google map and would like a infoWindow to pop up when I click on the polygon. Code as the follows:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', showVolume);
polygon_infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
```

In the showVolume function,

```
function showVolume(event){
    var polygon_Name = this.Name;
    var volume = this.Volume;
    var pt = event.latlng;
    var contentString = '<b>Name: </b>' + polygon_Name + '<br>' + '<b>Volume: </b>' + volume + '<br>' + '<b>Clicked Location: </b>' + pt;

    polygon_infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
    polygon_infoWindow.open(map);
    polygon_infoWindow.setPosition(pt);
}
```

The function returned the correct information belonging to the polygon. However it returned the event.latlng as undefined. I wonder what is wrong.

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: polygon_infoWindow is not defined`

Comment: My apologies, my definition was wrong because i changed my code to preserve confidential information. Now it's defined as polygon_infoWindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.latlng` doesn't exist, javascript is case sensitive, the property is `event.latLng`

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1f75mbga/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var polygon_infoWindow;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    Name: "Fred",
    Volume: 1000,
    path: [{
      lat: 37.4419,
      lng: -122.1419
    }, {
      lat: 37.42,
      lng: -122.16
    }, {
      lat: 37.4419,
      lng: -122.1819
    }]
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', showVolume);
  polygon_infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function showVolume(event) {
  var polygon_Name = this.Name;
  var volume = this.Volume;
  var pt = event.latLng;
  var contentString = '<b>Name: </b>' + polygon_Name + '<br>' + '<b>Volume: </b>' + volume + '<br>' + '<b>Clicked Location: </b>' + pt;

  polygon_infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  polygon_infoWindow.setPosition(pt);
  polygon_infoWindow.open(map);

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! latLng instead of LatLng. However, when I browsed Google documentation [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows), I found it saying LatLng.